# Excel VBA macro find Text in .doc files

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write a macro that can find the files having name XXXX_TestSummary in around 100 folders and search the word "Failed" in those files. Macro should return the filename that contain word failed in text or excel.

I am stuck as i can just find the file names in folder. Below is the code

```
Sub MainList()

    'Updateby20150706
    Set folder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If folder.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    xDir = folder.SelectedItems(1)
    Call ListFilesInFolder(xDir, True)

End Sub

Sub ListFilesInFolder(ByVal xFolderName As String, ByVal xIsSubfolders As Boolean)

    Dim xFileSystemObject As Object
    Dim xFolder As Object
    Dim xSubFolder As Object
    Dim xFile As Object
    Dim rowIndex As Long
    Set xFileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set xFolder = xFileSystemObject.GetFolder(xFolderName)
    rowIndex = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
      Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(rowIndex, 1).Formula = xFile.Name
      rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
    Next xFile
    If xIsSubfolders Then
      For Each xSubFolder In xFolder.SubFolders
        ListFilesInFolder xSubFolder.path, True
      Next xSubFolder
    End If
    Set xFile = Nothing
    Set xFolder = Nothing
    Set xFileSystemObject = Nothing

End Sub

Function GetFileOwner(ByVal xPath As String, ByVal xName As String)

    Dim xFolder As Object
    Dim xFolderItem As Object
    Dim xShell As Object
    xName = StrConv(xName, vbUnicode)
    xPath = StrConv(xPath, vbUnicode)
    Set xShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set xFolder = xShell.Namespace(StrConv(xPath, vbFromUnicode))
    If Not xFolder Is Nothing Then
      Set xFolderItem = xFolder.ParseName(StrConv(xName, vbFromUnicode))
    End If
    If Not xFolderItem Is Nothing Then
      GetFileOwner = xFolder.GetDetailsOf(xFolderItem, 8)
    Else
      GetFileOwner = ""
    End If
    Set xShell = Nothing
    Set xFolder = Nothing
    Set xFolderItem = Nothing

End Function
```

Can please anyone help to fix this ?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? And why do you need a macro? Are the folders listed in excel? Are all sub folders and sub folders of those, etc? Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: i am not getting any error, files in folder and sub folder are getting listed in excel but i am not able to find only .doc file & search failed word in doc file & list the file name which contain word failed.

Comment: Please can you help me in fixing this code its very important ???

Comment: why you need macro for searching a keyword in a doc file? just try direct search in a folder with advance options.

Comment: there are around 100 word files having this key word & i need to manually open & check each file

Answer (score 0):

If you are going with the code above, you will need to add some code within your loop:

```
For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
    Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(rowIndex, 1).Formula = xFile.Name
    (ADD CODE HERE)
    rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
Next xFile
```

or, alternatively, you could add an if statement toward the top of that loop to check if `xFile.Name` contains "Failed":

```
For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
    If InStr(xFile.Name, "Failed") Then
        Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(rowIndex, 1).Formula = xFile.Name
        rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
    End If
Next xFile
```

This way, you would only list the files that contain "Failed" in the text of their name.

Comment: thanks a lot for help but i need to find the Failed word in microsoft word document so now i am able to find the files having the name with _TESTSummary but i need to access the word document & find the word Failed in word document. could you please help me ?

Comment: The word document is having editing restriction or protected document 2013. please help

Comment: It sounds like you will need to use Microsoft Word API.  Once you select  your file, you will want to create an instance of Microsoft Word (or use an existing instance); then you will need to open the file and manipulate it using [Word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff837519.aspx) API commands

Comment: might be can you plz help on this i dont have any idea about word API